# How to set same path for category and post using htaccess in PHP?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am creating a blog system in PHP. I created categories and posts in my database. I have two pages to display categories-related posts and post viewer. I want to open category and post in the same path using .htaccess .
I have tried this htaccess code .

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ catlinks.php?id=$1 [L]
```

As you can see above, I created show.php for the post viewer and catlinks.php for the category-related posts.

when I open URL like -

```
example.com/postSlug
```

it works but when I open a category in the same path

```
example.com/categorySlug
```

it opens show.php and not found page.It doesn't point catlinks.php page
I can do it like this `example.com/category/categorySlug`. but I want to open on the same path -
like

```
example.com/this-is-my-post 
example.com/category-slug
```

Is it possible to open on same path?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules to point only one file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ show.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now, we are pointing to one file. In the same file, we can create two conditions when a post is found else when the category is found.
It all depends on your slug. The slug should be unique for post and category.
The solution is taken from https://technosmarter.com/php/create-categories-in-blog-using-php-and-mysql